# Matrices Multiplication $AB + BC = D$

Tags: matrices

Suppose I have the following equation $AB + BC=D$, where $A$, $C$, and $D$ are known, how can I derive the solution for $B$?

Comment: It's called [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) and there are ways to solve this. You might start with the Wikipedia link, or have a look at the [many](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=sylvester+equation) questions here about this equation.

Comment: Thank you! It helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is a [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation). Suppose that $B$ has shape $m \times n$. In terms of [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) and the Kronecker product, we have
$$
(I_n \otimes A + C^T \otimes I_m)\operatorname{vec}(B) = \operatorname{vec}(D).
$$
If the coefficient matrix is invertible, this can be solved as usual with
$$
\operatorname{vec}(B) = (I_n \otimes A + C^T \otimes I_m)^{-1}\operatorname{vec}(D).
$$

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot!